# jquery calendar datepicker does not work with my include php

Tags: php, jquery, html, include, datepicker

I met some trouble while using input type dates, also I decided for reasons of compatibility to change all input type date by type of text using class datepicker.

When I'm on index.php everything works fine.

When I'm on an other page for example index.php?p=home. Even if it displays the same page as index.php no calendar does appear.

Here is the code I use for changing the input.

```
<body onmousemove="resetTimer()" onload="startTimer();startTime();<?php if(isset($_GET['p']) AND $_GET['p']=='monitoring'){echo 'ajax();' ;}; ?>changefield()"> 
<!-- Script DATE  -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("input[type=date]").replaceWith("<input type='text' class='datepicker'/>");
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showWeek: true,
            beforeShowDay: '',
            showAnim: "show"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I really do not know how to find an issue to this problem.

Receive all my utmost Respect.

Kind Regards.

SP.

Comment: Check if on the other pages jQuery and the datepicker script are included correctly. You can see this in Firebug's Net tab.

Comment: I actualy use an other jquery <?php if(isset($_GET['p']) AND $_GET['p']!='abonnements' AND $_GET['p']!='releve_financiers') {?> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pstrength-min.1.2.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.password').pstrength();
});
</script>
<?php }?> I really need both of them And If I release this one all works, but if I don't have it my page will not work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work...

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5bE6d/)

maybe you don't include the jquery-ui script ?

Comment: In fact When I use that $("input[type=date]").each(function () { var $this = $(this); $this.replaceWith($('<input type="text" class="mydatepicker"/>').attr({ name: $this.attr("name"), id: $this.attr("id"), value: $this.attr("value") })); }); for keeping all information about the input it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo for starters:

```
A`ND $_GET['p']=='monitoring'
```

Comment: And this "answer" should have been posted as a comment. Also for starters. :)

Comment: Why should it have been added as a comment?

Comment: <body onmousemove="resetTimer()" onload="startTimer();startTime();<?php if(isset($_GET['p']) AND $_GET['p']=='monitoring'){echo 'ajax();' ;}; ?>changefield()">  here is the real code. This site change it when I try to post it as code I think I ve done something wrong while editing text

Comment: oh I'm sorry I did not see that. Thank you verry much .